# Automatically send SMS messages Windows 10

Tags: c#, sms

Is it possible to automatically send a text message from a button click? I'm coding a Windows 10 application in C#.

I think that Windows 8.1 cannot, but does the new Windows 10 apis allow this?

Comment: No. You need a 3rd party API for this. It will cost money.

Comment: Yes, it's possible on Windows 10, 8.1, 8, servers, android, linux,etc. just use the API!

Comment: Check out twillio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there is an [SMSMessage library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.pocketoutlook.smsmessage.aspx), this is limited to Windows Mobile which was the predecessor to Windows Phone.

Obviously, due to its age and limitations, it's severely outdated and you wouldn't want to use it. I'd have added this as a comment but I'm new to the site and can't. Hope this helps to clarify though!

Answer (score 0):

Nope. There is no such way across any flavor of Windows operating system as far as windows APIs are concerned. I believe it will equally apply to other operating systems available in market as well. While sending an SMS you will be using the telecom companies' infrastructure and their mobile network. There are vendors in market which provide such facility behalf of the telecom providers. I found a few blogs referring on how to use such libraries to send SMS:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19023/Sending-SMS-using-NET
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/b8d90a/send-sms-using-c-sharp-net/